# php data is not showing when href is changed . any solution?

Tags: php

This code works fine but i want to change $post_id with $post_slug. so in second code i have changed theme with $post_slug

```
<a href="posts.php?id=<?php echo $post_id;?> " > <img  src="images/<?php echo $record['post_image'];?>" /></a>

// posts.php 
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $post_id = $_GET['id'];
    $select_query = " SELECT * FROM `posts`where id='$post_id' ";
    $run_query = mysql_query($select_query);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_query)){
        $post_id = $row['id'];
        $post_image = $row['image'];
    }
?>
```

here i have changed $post_id with $post_slug.    But this time it's not working . posts.php is showing only footer.  any solution please

```
//index.php 

 <a href="posts.php?slug=<?php echo $post_slug;?> " > <img src="images/<?php echo $record['post_image'];?>"   /></a>


//posts.php 

<?php
if (isset($_GET['post_slug'])){
    $post_id = $_GET['post_slug'];
    $select_query = " SELECT * FROM `posts`where post_slug='$post_id' ";
    $run_query = mysql_query($select_query);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_query)){
        $post_slug = $row['post_slug'];
        $post_image = $row['image'];
    }
?>
```

or it simply does not work if i change  posts.php?id= to  posts.php?ab=

Comment: your code suffers from an sql injection vulnerability.  It's crucial you understand why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code

```
//index.php 
<a href="posts.php?slug=<?php echo $post_slug;?> " > <img src="images/<?php echo $record['post_image'];?>"   />
                </a>

//posts.php 
<?php
if (isset($_GET['slug'])) {
    $post_id = $_GET['slug'];
    $select_query = " SELECT * FROM `posts`where post_slug='$post_id' ";
    $run_query = mysql_query($select_query);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_query)) {
        $post_slug = $row['post_slug'];
        $post_image = $row['image'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: wow that was super fast  thank u very much ..... i thought  that  ab/id has no value . Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Please try with

```
$_GET['slug'] instead of $_GET['post_slug'].
```

And also make sure that $post_slug contains value.

```
//posts.php 
<?php
if (isset($_GET['slug'])) {
    $post_id = $_GET['slug'];
    $select_query = " SELECT * FROM `posts`where post_slug='$post_id' ";
    $run_query = mysql_query($select_query);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_query)) {
        $post_slug = $row['post_slug'];
        $post_image = $row['image'];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You checking wrong variable value
check "$_post['slug']" variable value

```
   <?php
    if (isset($_GET['slug'])){

    $post_id = $_GET['slug'];

    $select_query = " SELECT * FROM `posts`where post_slug='$post_id' ";
   // Do here any things

        }
    ?>
```